# wpf find element by name from another DataGridTextColumn

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, nested

I want to bind with with the Button that is another "`DataGridTemplateColumn`", I tried using `ElementName` but it is returning me `unset framework value` inside my converter. I want to change the row color depending on the button enable state, but this is a control that has nested `DataGrid`.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static loc:ManageRequirementsResource.lblName}" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="0.5*" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridDefaultColumnHeaderStyle}"
                                                            ElementStyle="{StaticResource UcPredecessorSuccessorEnableDisableStyle}"/>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static loc:ManageRequirementsResource.lblDescription}" Binding="{Binding Description}" Width="*" 
                                                                HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyleWithoutRightBorder}">
                                                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ToolTipWithContentTrimmedTextBlockStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                                        <Style.Resources>
                                                            <converters:MultiBindingPredecessorSuccessorIsEnabledConverter x:Key="MultiBindingPredecessorSuccessorIsEnabledConverter"/>
                                                        </Style.Resources>
                                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                                            <DataTrigger Value="False">
                                                                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBindingPredecessorSuccessorIsEnabledConverter}">
                                                                        <Binding />
                                                                        <Binding ElementName="This" Path="ViewModel.SelectedRequirement"/>






 ##### Unable to find, UnSetValue, it's in another column
    <Binding ElementName="btnAddCommand"/> 

##### Unable to find, UnSetValue, it's in another column                                                                                
    <Binding ElementName="btnAddCommand" Path="IsEnabled"/> 



                                                               </MultiBinding>
                                                                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                                                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GridHeaderBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                                                                </DataTrigger.Setters>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                        </Style.Triggers>

                                                    </Style>
                                                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>

                                            </DataGridTextColumn>

                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnNoBorderHeaderStyle}">
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <Button ToolTip="{x:Static reqPages:TraceabilityResource.linkToEditRequirementsTooltip}" Style="{StaticResource PopupMenueButtonStyle}" Click="LinkButton_OnClick" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Button_OnMouseLeftButtonUp">
                                                        <Image Source="/Project;component/Resources/Images/link.png" Height="13" Width="13" />
                                                    </Button>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnNoBorderHeaderStyle}" x:Name="DataGridTemplateColumn">
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                        <Grid>
                                                            <Grid.Style>
                                                                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btnAddCommand, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                                                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GridHeaderBackgroundBrush}" />
                                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                                </Style>
                                                            </Grid.Style>



**<!-- ######## I want to bind with this button ######-->**


                                                            <Button x:Name="btnAddCommand" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" Command="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=ViewModel.AddingCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Button_OnMouseLeftButtonUp" Style="{StaticResource PopupMenueButtonStyle}">
                                                                <Image  Height="20" >
                                                                    <Image.Source>
                                                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBindingPredecessorSuccessorImageSourceConverter}">
                                                                            <Binding/>
                                                                            <Binding ElementName="This" Path="ViewModel.SelectedRequirement"/>
                                                                            <Binding ElementName="btnAddCommand"/>
                                                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource self}" Path="IsEnabled"/>
                                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                                    </Image.Source>
                                                                </Image>
                                                                <Button.ToolTip>
                                                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBindingPredecessorSuccessorToolTipConverter}">
                                                                            <Binding/>
                                                                            <Binding ElementName="This" Path="ViewModel.SelectedRequirement"/>
                                                                            <Binding ElementName="btnAddCommand"/>
                                                                            <Binding ElementName="This" Path="ViewModel.IsSuccessor"/>
                                                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource self}" Path="IsEnabled"/>
                                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                                </Button.ToolTip>
                                                            </Button>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind to an element that is defined in the template of another column. They belong to different namescopes.

What you should do is to bind the properties of the elements in both column to the same source property.

For the property of the element in the second column to be updated when you change the property of the element in the first one and vice versa, your data object should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise change notifications for the data-bound source property.